# Whole House Humidifiers for Ductless Furnaces?

Tags: hvac

Is there a whole house humidifier that I can attach on my furnace that requires no ductwork? All we have for ductwork, is a galvanized pipe that sits on top of my furnace. There's a blower that blows the air up that one n only pipe,through a floor register. Our house is a 3,000 sq ft. home.

Comment: Does this furnace have a blower in it?

Comment: One thing to be aware of: there is a style of humidifier that sprays a mist of water into the duct and it evaporates into the circulating air.  It's simple to install on almost any shape duct, but minerals in the water form microscopic dust that also gets circulated.  You will find this collecting on surfaces in the house (and you'll be breathing it).  If you add a humidifier, use a style that evaporates water from some type of media.  The media will fill with the minerals and you replace it about once a year depending on how hard your water is.

Answer (score 1):

Your installation sounds as if your house originally had a coal furnace installed many years ago. Your description sounds like my grand mother's house. That being said, If the supply pipe is a rectangle with a flat surface, and you have a return air duct, almost any bypass type humidifier could be used. If the supply pipe is round, you would have to have a sheet metal shop make you a transition piece that would adapt to the round pipe and give you a flat surface to mount the humidifier on.This may be a lot for the average home owner to do but yes, it can and has been done.